# Building a distro from scratch without LFS

Tags: linux

I'm currently going through Linux from Scratch to build a distro. My reason for doing so is curiosity more than anything. I've not had any issues and learning a lot.

But, what I'd like to know is without Linux from Scratch are there any other ways to build a distro without using another distro as a base?

By this I mean if LFS wasn't around how else would you build a distro from scratch? I'm guessing Gentoo was created using a primitive approach.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: LFS *is* a compilation of techniques that were originally used to build most distros.  Really, getting kernel headers, building `glibc`, and compiling `gcc` as a cross compiler to build `glibc` and `gcc` once again in a new environment is pretty much the way to get a new OS.  You could use a different `libc` or a different compiler, but you will always need the compilation steps to glue the compiler, the c library and the kernel together.